# How do create a method within the enum class to return an array containing all the constants declared in this class

Tags: java, enums

```java
enum Cheese {
    MOZZARELLA,
    NONE,
    VEGAN;

    // Return constants array
    public static Cheese[] values() {
        Cheese[] cheeses = {
            Cheese.MOZZARELLA,
            Cheese.NONE,
            Cheese.VEGAN
        };
        return cheeses;
    }
}
```

This values() method returns an array of constants but gives me an error saying the method already defined;

[image: The return array should look like this]

I can't use the Cheese.values() method to extract all the constants from the Cheese class as I keep getting an ambiguous error as im trying to declare the method within the enum class itself.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 1):

You don't have to. The compiler aready adds a `values()` method.

```java
public enum Cheese {
    MOZARELLA,
    NONE,
    VEGAN
}

public class Program {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(Cheese.values()));
    }
}
```

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/enum.html:

> The compiler automatically adds some special methods when it creates an enum. For example, they have a static `values` method that returns an array containing all of the values of the enum in the order they are declared.

Quoting the Javadoc of [`Enum`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/19/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Enum.html#valueOf(java.lang.Class,java.lang.String)):

> All the constants of an enum class can be obtained by calling the implicit `public static T[] values()` method of that class.